# Clearing layered canvas text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question regarding layered canvas elements I'm experimenting with.

If I have two canvas', one (c1) z-index 1 and a second (c2) z-index 2, layered on top what's the best way to write text to c2, and clear it? I've tried a few ways so far but none seem perfect.

1. When I try to simply overwrite the text with the background color, I'm left with a slight outline of my text as if I've done a bad photoshop job!
2. If I try to use clearRect() on the c2 canvas with the background colour, it obviously makes the c2 canvas background solid and obscures a section of the c1 canvas.
3. If I try to draw the text on the c1 canvas and use clearRext, when a sprite moves behind the area it flickers as the sprite area is set to the background area before it's redrawn.

Any thoughts on a sensible approach here?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post, just do clearRect(), but then I remebered you had an issue with that.
Could you post your code so we can get a better feel for what is going on?

The clearRect function on a context sets the data in the area to 0. So, I am confused as to how it is making your background solid.

```
ctx2.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
// this should just clear the canvas2
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/crzyman/CHWkJ/) is a jsfiddle of what I mean.